# How to show a composable just for e few seconds?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a `Text` composable within a `Box`:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier)
) {
    Text(text = "BlaBla"    )
}
```

**How can show the Box/Text for a few seconds, only?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `LaunchedEffect` and delay with a boolean flag and set it false after time specified

```
@Composable
private fun TimedLayout() {
    var show by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        delay(5000)
        show = false
    }
    Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Box showing: $show")
        if(show){
            Box{
                Text(text = "BlaBla"    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of way you can achieve this, for instance:

You can use [`AnimatedVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility) in case you want to choose which animation you want.

Example:

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = yourFlag) { 
   Box{
      Text(text = "BlaBla")
   } 
}
```

If you are using a `ViewModel` or any pattern and you can *observe* you can create two states and then inside of the `ViewModel` / `Presenter` / Whatever you start the timer you want (doing this you can test it):

```
sealed class TextState {
  object Visible: TextState()
  object Invisible: TextState()
}
```

And then inside the `@Composable` you do this

```
val state by presenter.uiState.collectAsState()
    when (val newState = state) {
       Visible -> {}
       Invisible -> {}
    }
```

You can change it also playing with the `Alpha`

```
Modifier.alpha(if(isVisible) 1f else 0f)
```

Another valid option is what @Thracian commented, using [`Side-Effects`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)
for example :

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        try {
            initTimer(SECONDS_HERE) {
            //Timer has passed so you can show or hide
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            //Something wrong happened with the timer
        }
    })
}

suspend fun initTimer(time: Long, onEnd: () -> Unit) {
    delay(timeMillis = time)
    onEnd()
}
```