# How to reset remembered mutable state in composable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I used this [example from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333356/8707673):

```
@Composable
private fun TimedLayout() {
    var show by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        delay(5000)
        show = false
    }
    Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Box showing: $show")
        if(show){
            Box{
                Text(text = "BlaBla"    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works in my case fine for the first time. When I immediately call `TimedLayout()` again after the `Text()` disappeared, the remembered `show` flag remains `false` and no Text is showing up.

How can I start the composable with a fresh `show` as `true`? How can I solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is within in which scope `show` is cached. Next recomposition on `TimedLayout()` will enforce new key in the compose and therefore new value.

You need to move the state one level up or in the caller site.

Comment: This simple idea and LaunchedEffect(key1 = show){} solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

One possible easy solution is to set the show value to true in LaunchedEffect

```
@Composable
private fun TimedLayout() {
    var show by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        show = true
        delay(5000)
        show = false
    }
    Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Box showing: $show")
        if(show){
            Box{
                Text(text = "BlaBla"    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
@Composable
 fun TimedLayout() {
 var show by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = show){
    delay(5000)
    show = !show
}
Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text("Box showing: $show")
    if(show){
        Box{
            Text(text = "BlaBla"    )
        }
    }
}
```

}